# Jq json parsing for array elements

Tags: shell, curl, jq

I have a Json that I get like this by calling an api,how do i use a JQ query in curl to get the envname by passing 1111

```
{
  "EnvMappings": [
  {
    "EnvName": "lab",
    "Stores": [
       "1111",
       "2222"
     ]
 }
]
```

}

```
curl -s "<<MYAPI>>" | jq -Mr '.EnvMappings[].EnvName' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean to get all `EnvName` values that contains a certain value under `Stores`

```
.EnvMappings[] | select(any(.Stores[]; . == "1111")).EnvName
```